# Why aren't my mobs spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was turning it to normal mode from peaceful mode to play Minecraft. I tried spawning a zombie it wouldn't spawn

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! At the moment your question needs more information. If you could add the command/method you used to summon the zombie, as well as any error messages you may have received, it would help greatly.

Comment: That's kind of the point of "peaceful"…

Comment: unless the edit twisted the question Morgan says that he is playing in "NORMAL" and was in peaceful, therefor that is anything but expected.
Are you playing on a server in which case your settings are irellevant

Answer (score 2):

This is normal behavior. As taken from the Minecraft wiki:

> When any of these **(hostile)** mobs attempt to spawn (whether naturally, through mob spawners, spawn eggs, or commands), they are removed from the game instantaneously. When the difficulty is switched from any other setting to Peaceful, all mobs that are not allowed to spawn on Peaceful are removed from the world.
> https://minecraft.wiki/w/Difficulty#Peaceful

Bolded words in the above quote I added myself.

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure that its not an issue with difficulties and you're running on Easy/Normal/Hard then the only thing that comes to my mind that could be the issue is /gamerules AllowMobSpawn, you might have it on False for some reason, swith it to "true" via the command "/Gamerule AllowMobSpawn True"